# Две кнопки вызывают одну функцию с разным результатом

Tags: python, pyqt, сигналы-слоты, qpushbutton, pyside6

Как сделать такое:

- два виджета, например кнопки, дёргают одну функцию-слот с разным результатом.

Минимально воспроизводимый пример:

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *


def show_message():
    print("button1")
    #print("button2")


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QWidget()
    window.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 200)  
    vbox = QVBoxLayout()
    button1 = QPushButton("button1", window)
    button1.clicked.connect(show_message)
    button2 = QPushButton("button2", window)
    button2.clicked.connect(show_message)
    vbox.addWidget(button1)
    vbox.addWidget(button2)
    window.setLayout(vbox)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Добавлю. Лучше, чтобы это были не кнопки, а например два спинбокса. Тогда функция-слот пусть возвращает выбранное значение (value) и имя виджета (или его id или ещё что-то).

Comment: И что? в чём вопрос? В зависимости от нажатой кнопки функция должна что то делать?

Comment: В таком случае "а например два спинбокса." тогда и код измените.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот такое было нужно

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *


class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        spinbox1 = QSpinBox()
        spinbox1.setObjectName('spinbox1')
        spinbox1.valueChanged.connect(self.show_message)
        spinbox2 = QSpinBox()
        spinbox2.setObjectName('spinbox2')
        spinbox2.valueChanged.connect(self.show_message)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(spinbox1)
        vbox.addWidget(spinbox2)

    def show_message(self, value):
        sender = self.sender()
        print(value, sender.objectName())
 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: а вам не приходит в голову что так делать не правильно. Вы спросили, я вам ответил. Вы берете мой ответ, меняете там виджет и говорите что ваш ответ теперь будет правильным.

Comment: Вы не ответили, чем ваш ответ отличается от предоставленного моего ответа? Ответьте пожалуйста.

Comment: После вопроса было ещё "Добавлю. Лучше, чтобы это были не кнопки, а например два спинбокса....". Мой ответ про это дополнительное условие. Ваш ответ тоже получил свою зелёную галочку.

Comment: 1. Если вы хотите изменить или дополнить свой вопрос, вам надо нажать кнопку `Править` и внести эти изменения/ дополнения в теле вопроса, а не в комментариях. 2. По сути не важно, какой виджет вы используете,  ответ на ваш вопрос заключается в строке `sender = self.sender()`

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

> PySide6.QtCore.QObject.[**sender()**](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtCore/QObject.html#PySide6.QtCore.PySide6.QtCore.QObject.sender)
>
> Возвращает указатель на объект, отправивший сигнал, если он вызван в слоте, активированном сигналом; в противном случае возвращается `None`. 
> Указатель действителен только во время выполнения слота, который вызывает эту функцию из контекста потока этого объекта.

```
import sys
'''
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *
'''
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
   
    
class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.button1 = QPushButton("button1")
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.show_message)
        self.button2 = QPushButton("button2")
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.show_message)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button1)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button2)

    def show_message(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        print(f'{sender.text()}')
 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 200) 
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]